# AWS duplicating EC2 instances makes it point to the same domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an `EC2` instance that host a wordpress site.

Then I have created `AMI` image with it and created exact copy of the instance.

The instance that I have copied from is linked to a domain through `Route 53`.

A bizarre experience that I have right now is that (twice now), when I copy `EC2` instances in a way described above, using HTTP to access either of the `EC2` instances lead to re-routing to the domain that was routed by `Route 53` for the first instance.

Shouldn't only the first instance be linked to the domain because that is how I have set the record in `Route 53`? Is it normal for duplicated `EC2` instance to point to same domain when I copy it using `AMI` image? How do I make it so that the second copied instance does not get re-routed to the same domain as the first instance?

Comment: Where is the DB for this install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really is unrelated to AWS, EC2, Route53, etc. You simply have the "Site Address" setting in your Wordpress configuration set as that specific domain name. Wordpress automatically redirects any incoming requests to the configured Site Address.

Comment: oh wow... yes... that's the problem. Thank you very much spent 3 days on it.